# Crossword With Friends

Tags: anagram, crosswords

So I recently created a crossword for you guys, but I misplaced everything except my list of words! Being too busy working on movie-related puzzles to recreate it, I asked some help from my friends (you guys know how I love layers in my puzzles).

First, I had my friend Al Literation (you may remember him) write the clues based on my words.

Then I gave the vertical answers to my friend Anna Graham to write down in the crossword image.

Finally I gave the horizontal words to my amigo Juan Hamming-Distans (what's that, a stretch you say? Get over it, a theme is a theme) so he could write them in the crossword.

Anna and Juan each altered the words they were given to new words (their transformations did not alter the length of my words) and redrew the crossword so that they could make them fit together. That's what you see below. You can find Al's clues below; for each one, determine my original word and, based on whether they're down or across, figure out what Anna or Juan did to them before placing them in the crossword (there will almost always be only one possibility). All words (my original ones and the modified ones) can be found on dictionary.com

#### Crossword

[image: Crossword]

| Horizontal | Vertical |
| --- | --- |
| 4. Battlewise bravery | 1. Shadowy Sherlock |
| 5. Sans sensation | 2. Charismatic quality |
| 8. Medical mesh material | 3. Hired helping hand |
| 10. Anaerobically assembled acid | 6. Sprinkles salvation |
| 12. Opposite of old origin offensive | 7. Pixelated puerile protagonist |
| 13. Pertaining preposition | 9. Cosmological cloud |
| 15. Sound system segment | 11. Dull discomforts |
| 20. Decided determination | 14. Rising rocket requirement |
| 21. Observe outlook on oracular orbs | 16. Ambush assault |
| 22. Rifle rest | 17. Spear's similar |
| 23. Devilish, deemed Dante | 18. Deviate direction |
| 25. Constant current classification | 19. Accomplish again |
| 28. Vowelless vituperation | 24. Metal mixture |
| 29. African antelope | 26. These three things |
| 30. Painlessly punish progeny | 27. Scared swallow |

Comment: Oh, yeah. I know Juan. Nice guy.

Comment: Can someone please help me understand Juan's name...

Comment: @Bailey: One Hamming Distance.

Comment: Google explained it to me. Thank you~

Comment: @NeedAName: Can you please confirm that the tense of "observe" in 21 across is correct?

Comment: @dpwilson it is correct. The verb answer is in the same tense as observe (first person simple present IIRC)

Answer (score 5):

### PARTIAL ANSWER

Here's what I've come up with so far. I'm very close; I just need to finish the upper-right corner. I was too lazy to put letters into the crossword image, so hopefully someone else can verify that this all works. (Sidenote: This is my first answer on this website, so any suggestions on proper formatting would be appreciated!)

**Edit 1:** Answered 1 Down.

### Horizontal

4 Battlewise bravery

> Valor → Vapor

5 Sans sensation

> Dull → Dill

8 Medical mesh material

> Gauze → Gauge

10 Anaerobically assembled acid

> Lactic → Tactic

12 Opposite of old origin offensive

> Occidental → Accidental

13 Pertaining preposition

> About → Abort

15 Sound system segment

> Speaker → Sneaker

20 Decided determination

> Resolve → Revolve

21 Observe outlook on oracular orbs

> Peer → Seer

22 Rifle rest

> Bipod → Biped

23 Devilish, deemed Dante

> Material → Maternal

25 Constant current classification

> Direct → Direst

28 Vowelless vituperation

> Tsk → Ask

29 African antelope

> Oryx → Onyx

30 Painlessly punish progeny

> Ground → Around

### Vertical

1 Shadowy Sherlock

> Sleuth → Hustle

2 Charismatic quality

> Charm → March

3 Hired helping hand

> Aide → Idea

6 Sprinkles salvation

> Anoints → Nations

7 Pixelated puerile protagonist

> Link → Kiln

9 Cosmological cloud

> Nebula → Unable

11 Dull discomforts

> Aches → Chase

14 Rising rocket requirement

> Thrust → Truths

16 Ambush assault

> Raid → Arid

17 Spear's similar

> Pike → Kepi

18 Deviate direction

> Veer → Ever

19 Accomplish again

> Redo → Rode

24 Metal mixture

> Alloy → Loyal

26 These three things

> Words → Sword

27 Scared swallow

> Gulp → Plug

Comment: Welcome to the site @dpwilson and great job on making so much progress. I edited your post to fix the numbers (the site auto formats numbered points to ascend one at a time and overrides your numbering eg 4 6 9 13 becomes 4 5 6 7). You have just 3 answers incorrect (answers to clues that is, all of your transformations are correct). As for Clue 1, think synonymous noun rather than proper noun example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @NeedAName. I put an answer to 1 Down. Time to track down the other two incorrect ones.

Comment: I wasn't counting 1 down as incorrect since you hadn't posited an answer on that one. There are three incorrect guesses, and all are located in the horizontal clues.